# Copy Function Not Pasting When Data Set is Filtered

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which is used to copy the active line and paste it a number of times at the first blank, or available line, at the end of the data. The code prompts the user to specify the number of times to paste the copied row at the end of the data. 
However, it is not working properly when the data set it is being used on is filtered on a certain field. Instead it is pasting over existing data that is within the filtered data. For example, if the row 699 is not visible because of the filter choice being applied and the data ends at row 700, so 701 would be the first blank row, it is pasting over row 699. However, it does work when the user saves in between. 
Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

```
Sub Transfer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("ForecastedMovement").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row    '   or + 1

On Error GoTo Finish
lngRows = CLng(InputBox("How many rows do you wish to add?"))
lngNextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":BX" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
Range("A" & lastrow + 1 & ":BX" & lastrow + lngRows).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Finish:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Prompt:="Please ensure you only enter numeric values!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a tip, use `Application.InputBox` instead of `InputBox`. You can then force the user to enter a number instead of using `On Error`. i.e. **`Application.InputBox("How many rows do you wish to add?", Type:=1)`**. This will only accept a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Transfer()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, lngRows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sht = Sheets("ForecastedMovement")

    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'account for filtered rows at end of dataset
    Do While Application.CountA(sht.Rows(lastrow)) > 0
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    Loop

    On Error GoTo Finish
    lngRows = CLng(InputBox("How many rows do you wish to add?"))

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("A1:BX1").Copy

    sht.Cells(lastrow, 1).Resize(lngRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Finish:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Prompt:="Please ensure you only enter numeric values!"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```